# Error in ruby : undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, undefined

I get an error while trying to program ruby. 
    Error : C:/Users/PC ASUS/Desktop/g.rb:3:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method 'y' for    main:Object (NameError)`

Here is my code:

```
puts " Do you like to install hacking pack?"
insta_one = gets.chomp

if insta_one == y
make
else 
puts "Ok. Bye!"
end

def make
awe = file.new("shell.bat","w")
readme.puts("@echo off")
readme.puts("color a")
readme.puts("echo Installing hacking pack")
readme.puts("Thanks for downloading rootShell!")
readme.puts("My email - cyniclimbu@gmail.com")
end
```

Comment: You're comparing ``ìnsta_one``` to an unexistant ```y``` variable. What you want is : ```if insta_one == 'y'```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can use a method, you need to define it. In your code, `make` is defined *after* you try to call it, so ruby is not familiar with it, and throws an error:

```
def make
  File.open("shell.bat", 'w') do |readme|
    readme.puts("@echo off")
    readme.puts("color a")
    readme.puts("echo Installing hacking pack")
    readme.puts("Thanks for downloading rootShell!")
    readme.puts("My email - cyniclimbu@gmail.com")
  end
end

puts " Do you like to install hacking pack?"
insta_one = gets.chomp

if insta_one == 'y'
  make
else 
  puts "Ok. Bye!"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`y` is not string but undefined variable.

Please change line 3:

```
if insta_one == 'y'
```

Comment: Thanks but now it gives me an error that the 'make' is undefined

Comment: `make` is method. Define method before call function. In `make` method, please change `file.new(...` to `File.new(...`. Because `File` is class, it should be capitalized for call class method.

Comment: It still gives me the error

Comment: undefined local variable or method

Comment: Please change `readme` into `awe`, because `readme` is undefined variable, then will work this code.

Comment: Did it, still wont work

Comment: @CaptainAmerica - you should define `make` _before_ you use it...